# Why printing an address changes their address?

Tags: c, pointers

Consider this code:

```
    int a = 2;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 7;
```

When compiling it stores them in the order I assign them:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2 ; int a = 2
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 5 ; int b = 5
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 7 ; int c = 7
        ...
```

But if I decide to print the address of b, now b switched with c their addresses:

```
    int a = 2;
    int b = 5;
    int c = 7;
    printf("%d\n", &b);
```

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 2 ; int a = 2
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], 5 ; int b = 5
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 7 ; int c = 7
        ...
```

So why do they switch addresses? By the way, I'm using gcc 12.2.

Comment: Note that in your question, you have the wrong comments for `b` and `c` in your second assembly block.

Comment: Why do you think the compiled code should retain any particular order?  Would the behavior of the code change if you defined `int c;` first?  And `printf("%d\n", &b);` is wrong - addresses are not `int` values, they are pointer values with the correct format specifier being `%p` - as long as the pointer is a `void *` pointer.  `printf("%p\n", ( void * )&b);` would be correct.

Comment: Maybe your compiler is, in it's own peculiar way, trying to warn you about the undefined behaviour elicited from trying to print an address with the `%d` format specifier?

Comment: Why worry about it? Gcc outputs all sorts of weird code. If the weird code isn't in optimized output and isn't a missed optimization, I wouldn't worry about it at all, unless I was trying to hack gcc.

Comment: @PSkocik You know, I don't really worry about it, I'm just interested about knowing why the compiler made that choice.

Comment: @Shai20 I'm too lazy to go analyze the source code but if you play with it by adding more variables (https://www.godbolt.org/z/rPx1f7f1d), it looks like the compiler's strategy is to divide the vars into those that did not have their address taken (possible register vars) and those that did and then allocate them in this order, thereby putting the latter group nearer the end of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

[The Compiler Explorer](https://www.godbolt.org/) uses gcc 12.2 and does not show this behaviour.

I tried compiling this code myself and gdb shows the "correct" order.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
    int a=2;
    int b=5;
    int c=7;
    printf("%d", b);
    return 0;
}
```

gdb output of "disassemble main":

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x0000000000401126 <+0>:    push   rbp
0x0000000000401127 <+1>:    mov    rbp,rsp
0x000000000040112a <+4>:    sub    rsp,0x10
0x000000000040112e <+8>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x2
0x0000000000401135 <+15>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x5
0x000000000040113c <+22>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc],0x7
0x0000000000401143 <+29>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]
0x0000000000401146 <+32>:   mov    esi,eax
0x0000000000401148 <+34>:   mov    edi,0x402010
0x000000000040114d <+39>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x0000000000401152 <+44>:   call   0x401030 <printf@plt>
0x0000000000401157 <+49>:   mov    eax,0x0
0x000000000040115c <+54>:   leave  
0x000000000040115d <+55>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Comment: It is: https://www.godbolt.org/z/7dEnr1TaE. You transcribed OP's code wrong, ommitting the `&` before `b`.

Comment: I also used godbolt but I printed `&b` and not `b`, like PSkocik pointed out.